# populating unordered list from pop up window into main window - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

In my parent window, I have a list :

```
<span id="r_doc_span">
<ul id="r_docs">
<li>
<input id="r_doctor" type="hidden" name="r_doctor" size="40" value="<%=rd%>">
<input id="r_doctor_ohip" type="hidden" name="r_doctor_ohip" size="20" value=<%=rdohip%>>
</li>
</ul></tr>
```

I want to populate this list from a pop-up window. I have 2 javascript functions for this purpose:

```
function addRefDoc(){
  <% prop = (Properties) vec.get(i1);
  String ref_no = prop.getProperty("referral_no","");
  String ref_name = (prop.getProperty("last_name", "")+ ","+prop.getProperty("first_name", "")); %>
 AddOtherRefDoc("<%=ref_name%>", <%=ref_no%>);
}

function AddOtherRefDoc(name, number) {
 var remove = "<a href='javascript:void(0) onclick='removeRefDoctor(this)'>remove</a>";
 var html = "<li>"+name+"<b>, Referral No: </b>"+number+ " " +remove+"</li>";
 jQuery("#r_docs").append(jQuery(html));
}
```

But nothing happens with this code. How can I populate my list? Please help.

Comment: `addRefDoc` is not JavaScript.

Comment: It's got embedded JSP code in it. It is JavaScript.

Comment: Now that you've edited it, yes. The original was missing some *fairly crucial* `<%` / `%>` tags. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>As Matt Ball said, at least one of your quoted functions for the popup isn't JavaScript, looks more like C#.</s> Now with the edit, the `<%` / `%>` are there.

From a popup window, you can access elements with `id`s on the parent window like this:

```
var doctor = window.opener.jQuery('#r_doctor');
```

That gets a reference to the `r_doctor` element on the parent window via the jQuery object in that window. (Child windows get a reference to their parent via the `window.opener` property.)

Here's a [live example](http://jsbin.com/ecaba4), the meat of the code (e.g., the line above) being [here in the popup](http://jsbin.com/odoqo3/edit). There I've used a `text` rather than `hidden` input, but that's just so you can see what's going on.